# Search text for specific keywords at start and end in php

Tags: php

I have the following string

```
$url_part = 'p=link&u=shuja&sort=recent';
```

I want to get string start with p= and end with & in such a way,

```
$page = 'link';
```

and it may exist anywhere in $url_parts. Then remove the same like that

```
$url_part = 'u=shuja&sort=recent';
```

Comment: I believe you can use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url_part = 'p=link&u=shuja&sort=recent';
$params = array();
parse_str($url_part, $params);
$page = isset($params['p']) ? $params['p'] : null;
unset($params['p']);
$url_part = http_build_query($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url_part = 'p=link&u=shuja&sort=recent';
$start=strpos($url_part,"p=");
$end=strpos($url_part,"&",$start);
$my_value=substr($url_part,$start+2,$end-2) // get link
$url_part=strstr($url_part, $my_value,true); // remove unwnated url // this line only for PHP 5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use explode like this

```
$url=explode('&',$url_part);
$page='';
for($i=0;$i<count($url);$i++) {
    $p=explode('=',$url[$i]);

    if($p[1]=='link')
        $page='link';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
$url_part = 'p=link&u=shuja&sort=recent';
//use this function instead to extract url_part to an array of argument
parse_str($url_part,$output);
//remove argument 'p' from array
unset($output['p']);
//create the url query again
$url_part = http_build_query($output); 
//will output string "u=shuja&sort=recent"
echo $url_part;
?>
```